# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0) Python and tkinter and Mysql

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter, mysql-workbench

I need help. I have a `patient_results_tbl` as shown below and I want to retrieve `voltage` and `time` based on the `patient_id` and `date`, exact much.

```
# patient_id,    voltage,     time,          date
'260939631',     '329',       '18:34:37',    '2021-11-05'
'260939631',     '334',       '18:34:39',    '2021-11-05'
'260939631',     '352',       '18:34:39',    '2021-11-05'
'260939631',     '341',       '18:51:01',    '2021-11-13'
'260939631',     '338',       '18:51:02',    '2021-11-13'
'260939631',     '331',       '18:51:03',    '2021-11-13'
'260939631',     '324',       '18:51:04',    '2021-11-13'
'260939631',     '319',       '18:51:05',    '2021-11-13'
'785393661',     '274',       '18:58:07',    '2021-11-13'
'785393661',     '280',       '18:58:08',    '2021-11-13'
'785393661',     '285',       '18:58:08',    '2021-11-13'
'785393661',     '290',       '18:58:09',    '2021-11-13'
```

The code am using is as follows:

```
def analyze_voltage_time():
            start_point = int(start_point_entry.get()) # getting from entry box
            end_point = int(end_point_entry.get())  # getting from entry box
            step = int(step_point_entry.get())  # getting from entry box
            start = get_date2()  # getting from tkcalender date picker
            _id = id_selector.get() # # getting from combobox
            pat_id = _id[:9]
            #query = "SELECT voltage, time FROM patient_results_tbl where patient_id =  " +pat_id
            #mycursor.execute(query, )
            query = "SELECT voltage, time FROM patient_results_tbl WHERE 'date' =%s AND 'patient_id' =%s"
            mycursor.execute(query, (start, pat_id))
            result = mycursor .fetchall()
            print(result)  # For checking 
            print(start)     # For checking purpose 
            print(pat_id)   # For checking purpose
            voltage, time = list(zip(*result))  # ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
            for volts in voltage:
                voltage_container.append(volts)
            for tim in time:
                time_container.append(str(tim))
            try:
                user_data = range(start_point, end_point, step)
                for i in user_data:
                    plt_voltage.append(voltage_container[i])
                    plt_time.append(time_container[i])
    
            except ValueError:
                user_data = range(start_point, end_point)
                for i in user_data:
                    plt_voltage.append(voltage_container[i])
                    plt_time.append(time_container[i])
                
            my_ax1.plot(plt_time, plt_voltage, color="red")        
            my_canvas1.draw_idle()
            analyse_btn['state'] = DISABLED
```

Running the above code as a standalone app gives me the following error:

```
[]
05/11/2021
260939631
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kennedy Mulenga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Kennedy Mulenga\Desktop\Level 5\18136709_BIT_280_Arduino_ECG_Project\18136709\18136709_ECG_LArdmon_APP_Final.py", line 418, in <lambda>
    analyse_btn = Button( tools_frame, text='Analyse', width = 8, height = 2, command = lambda :[get_date2(), analyze_voltage_time()])
  File "C:\Users\Kennedy Mulenga\Desktop\Level 5\18136709_BIT_280_Arduino_ECG_Project\18136709\18136709_ECG_LArdmon_APP_Final.py", line 285, in analyze_voltage_time
    voltage, time = list(zip(*result))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

If I run with the commented out query it returns all the records with respect to the patient_id which is ok.
And also running the query `SELECT voltage, time FROM patient_results_tbl WHERE date = 13/11/2021 AND patient_id = 785393661` directly in `Mysql` workbench return `0 rows`, but if I replace `AND` with `OR` am getting some results

```
# patient_id    voltage    time       date
785393661       274        18:58:07   2021-11-13
785393661       280        18:58:08   2021-11-13
785393661       285        18:58:08   2021-11-13
785393661       290        18:58:09   2021-11-13
```

I don't know where am not doing well, or is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide your code as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's easier to try and fix if we can copy paste and get the same error immediately.

The date you input into the query is in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" but your table has it in the format "yyyy-mm-dd". Therefore your results ends up as an empty list, which you can see as it's printed above your traceback, which is giving you the `ValueError`.

Comment: when inserting into the DB that format is accepting, but I have changed it to suit what the DB is displaying and I have found a way that's working.

Comment: @Kennerdol apologies, hard to find the issue without the actual database

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the line :

```
query = "SELECT voltage, time FROM patient_results_tbl WHERE 'date' =%s AND 'patient_id' =%s"
            mycursor.execute(query, (start, pat_id))
```

with:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT voltage, time FROM patient_results_tbl WHERE date =%s AND patient_id =%s", (start, pat_id))
```

by removing the quotes around `date` and `pat_id`
which has worked now, and if there is a better way to do it I will appreciate it and thanks.